# Update single state object from more than one React Date Picker input

Tags: reactjs, react-datepicker

Trying to update state object `data` from two [React Date Pickers](https://reactdatepicker.com/) embedded in bigger contolled form but can't do this. Any ideas what am I missing? Thank you in advance.

**Live preview here:** https://codesandbox.io/s/autumn-https-nyr28?file=/src/App.js

```js
export default function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState({
    async: true,
    from: "",
    to: ""
  });

  const handleChange = event => {
    let target = event.target;
    let value = target.type === "checkbox" ? target.checked : target.value;
    let name = target.name;
    setData(previousSearchData => ({
      ...previousSearchData,
      [name]: value
    }));
  };

  const handleSubmit = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log(data);
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      Checkbox:{" "}
      <input
        name="async"
        type="checkbox"
        checked={data.checkbox}
        onChange={handleChange}
      />
      <br />
      From:{" "}
      <ReactDatePicker
        name="from"
        selected={data.from}
        onChange={handleChange}
        timeInputLabel="Start time:"
        dateFormat="yyyy/MM/dd h:mm aa"
        showTimeInput
      />
      To:{" "}
      <ReactDatePicker
        name="to"
        selected={data.to}
        onChange={handleChange}
        timeInputLabel="End time:"
        dateFormat="yyyy/MM/dd h:mm aa"
        showTimeInput
      />
      <input type="submit" value="submit" />
    </form>
  );
}
```

Comment: If possible can you copy this over to a JS Fiddle, Codepen.io or something so that we can reproduce?

Comment: Sure, sorry for the latency but it was hard to make it work. Live preview link updated to the original post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This plugin does not send a js event object after it gets its input changed, it sends a js Date object, as you can see in the oficial page:

```
<DatePicker selected={startDate} onChange={date => setStartDate(date)} />
```

You will need to create a handler function specifically for inputs of this kind.

Something like:

```
<DatePicker selected={startDate} onChange={date => handleDatePickerChange('startDate', date)} />
```

...

```
const handleDatePickerChange = (name, date) => {
    setData(previousSearchData => ({
      ...previousSearchData,
      [name]: date
    }));
};
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Paolo. Didn't figured it out before. Worked like a charm and even don't get the React's uncontrolled error message now.